# ODE methods for solving diatomic equation of motion

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Referencing *Applied Quantum Mechanics* by *A.F.J.Lwei*:

Let $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$ be mass of two classical particle in a diatomic molecule.

The equation of motion is governed by

$$m_{1}\frac{d^{2}u_{1}}{dt^{2}}$ = $k(u_{2} - u_{1})$$

and

$$m_{2}\frac{d^{2}u_{2}}{dt^{2}}$ = $k(u_{1} - u_{2})$$

Where $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ is the displacement for $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$, respectively. $k$ is the spring constant connecting the two particles.

The author claims that the solution to above is of the form $e^{{-i\omega}t}$
and claims it leads to (I am unable to see)

$$(k - m_{1}{\omega}^{2})u_{1} - ku_{2} = 0$$

and

$$-ku_{1} + (k - m_{2}{\omega}^{2})u_{2} = 0$$

**Attempt:**

Letting $\omega^{2} = \frac{k}{m_{1}}$

$$\frac{d^{2}u_{1}}{dt^{2}} - \omega^{2}(u_{2} - u_{1}) = 0$$

gives

$$\frac{d^{2}u_{1}}{dt^{2}} = \omega^{2}(u_{2} - u_{1})$$

further reducing to

$$\frac{d^{2}u_{1}}{dt^{2}} - \omega^{2}u_{1} = \omega^{2}u_{2}$$

having the form of a second order non - homogeneous linear differential equation.

It's been years since I've touched ODEs. Could someone show me the steps?

Comment: Putting $ e^{-i\omega t}$ into the ODEs, what do you get?

Comment: @KenHung is there a body of theory that motivates the general form solution being $e^{{-i\omega}t}$?

Comment: You can view the ODEs in different perspectives. If you look at the physical motion that the ODE corresponds to and realizing the motion is periodic in itself. You will choose the ansatz (a guessed solution) as a periodic one.

Comment: @KenHung Makes sense. The hinted general solution encodes sinusoidal behaviors via Euler's formula. I have substitute the hinted solution into the first equation to no avail. Can you submit a brief solution? Happy to accept and upvote.

Comment: @KenHung solved

Answer (score 1):

Assuming permanent regimen and null initial conditions and also making $u_1 = u_{01}e^{j\omega t},\ u_2=u_{02}e^{j\omega t}$ we have

$$
\cases{
m_1(-\omega^2)u_{01}e^{j\omega t}=k(u_{02}e^{j\omega t}-u_{01}e^{j\omega t})\\
m_2(-\omega^2)u_{02}e^{j\omega t}=k(u_{01}e^{j\omega t}-u_{02}e^{j\omega t})
}
$$

or simplifying

$$
\cases{
(k-m_1\omega^2)u_{01}=ku_{02}\\
(k-m_2\omega^2)u_{02}=k u_{01}
}
$$